# Dynamically loading assemblies in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, assemblies, dynamic

I'm currently trying to dynamically load an assembly from within a asp.net httphandler. I have a dll that is built as part of a seperate library and my project contains a reference to said DLL and is deployed along with the service with CopyLocal true. I create a throwaway object to get the assembly path and I have confirmed the existence of the dll within the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder, but calling GetTypes() throws an exception.

I do something like:

```
string assemblyPath = new SomeClassInAssembly().GetType().Assembly.Location;
Type[] types = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath).GetTypes();
```

I cannot add the assembly to the GAC since that would defeat what I am trying to do with the service (think sandbox service that loads assemblies when necessary) and I cannot find anything that has been able to fix my problem thus far.

For reference I'm using VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Since you compile your web application with a reference to the assembly i don't see your need to load it using Assembly.LoadFrom. The GetTypes should be available using:

```
Type[] types = typeof(SomeClassInAssembly).Assembly.GetTypes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh, I finally hooked up to the exception and looked at the LoaderMessage and I was missing a referenced assembly.